# Having issues getting an inherited class working properly

Tags: c#, inheritance

Here is my base class :

```
    class Pet
    {
        //class internal variables
        string petName;
        bool gender;  //true = female; false = male
        DateTime dob;
        int goodDogs = 0;
        int goodCats = 0;
        int goodKids = 0;

        //constructors
        public Pet(string pn, bool g, DateTime birth, int d, int c, int k)
        {
            petName = pn;
            gender = g;
            dob = birth;
            goodDogs = d;
            goodCats = c;
            goodKids = k;
        }

        public Pet(string pn, string g, DateTime birth, int d, int c, int k)
        {
            petName = pn;
            if (g.ToLower() == "female")
            {
                gender = true;
            }
            else
            {
                gender = false;
            }
            dob = birth;
            goodDogs = d;
            goodCats = c;
            goodKids = k;
        }

        //Properties
        public string PetName
        {
            get
            {
                return petName;
            }
            set
            {
                petName = value;
            }
        }

        public string Gender
        {
            get
            {
                if (gender == true)
                {
                    return "Female";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Male";
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (value.ToLower() == "female")
                {
                    gender = true; 
                }
                else
                {
                   gender = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public DateTime DOB
        {
            get
            {
                return dob;
            }
            set
            {
                dob = value;
            }
        }

        public string GoodWithDogs
        {
            get
            {
                switch (goodDogs)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return "Yes";
                        //break;
                    case 2:
                        return "No";
                        //break;
                    default:
                        return "Unknown";
                        //break;
                }

            }
            set
            {
                goodDogs = int.Parse(value);
            }
        }

        public string GoodWithCats
        {
            get
            {
                switch (goodCats)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return "Yes";
                    //break;
                    case 2:
                        return "No";
                    //break;
                    default:
                        return "Unknown";
                    //break;
                }

            }
            set
            {
                goodCats = int.Parse(value);
            }
        }

        public string GoodWithKids
        {
            get
            {
                switch (goodKids)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return "Yes";
                    //break;
                    case 2:
                        return "No";
                    //break;
                    default:
                        return "Unknown";
                    //break;
                }

            }
            set
            {
                goodKids = int.Parse(value);
            }
        }

       // Methods
        public string GetAge()
        {
            DateTime currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan daysPassed = currentDate - dob;
            int ageInDays = daysPassed.Days;
            if (ageInDays < 350)
            {
                return (Math.Round(ageInDays / 30.0)).ToString() + " months";
            }
            else
            {
                return (ageInDays / 365).ToString("N1") + " years" ; 
            }
        }
    }

Here is what I have for my class that is trying to inherit:

public class Cat : Pet
{
    private string breed;
    private bool litterBoxTrained;
    private bool declawed;

    public Cat(string pn, string g, DateTime birth, int d, int c, int k,string b, bool lbt, bool dc) 
    : base ( pn, g, birth, d, c, k)
    {
        breed = b;
        litterBoxTrained = lbt;
        declawed = dc;
    }

    public string Breed
    {
        get
        {
            return breed;
        }
        set
        {
            breed = value;
        }
    }

    public string HouseBroke
    {
        get
        {
            if (litterBoxTrained == true)
            {
                return "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                return "No";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                litterBoxTrained = true;
            }
            else
            {
                litterBoxTrained = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public string BasicCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (declawed == true)
            {
                return "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                return "No";
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                declawed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                declawed = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public string InfoListing()
    {

        return string.Format("{0,-6}{1:-15}{2,-9}{3,-24}{4:-12}", "CAT", petName, gender, breed, base.GetAge());
    }
}
```

I am having issues with protection.  I am getting inconsistent class protection error and two errors trying to access the inherited variable petName and inherited method GetAge().  One of the caveats is that I am not allowed to alter the base (pet) class code.

Any advivce would be great.  Thank You

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting inconsistent class protection error

That's because `Pet` is implicitly `internal` (assuming it's a top-level class):

```
class Pet
```

whereas `Cat` is `public`:

```
public class Cat : Pet
```

You can't use an `internal` class as the base class for a `public` class. Either make `Pet` public, or `Cat` internal.

> and two errors trying to access the inherited variable petName

Despite the misleading comment above it, this variable:

```
 string petName;
```

is private, as that's the default for members within a class. So the compiler's absolutely right to prohibit you from using it outside `Pet`, even within a derived class. You should use the `PetName` property instead.

> and inherited method GetAge()

Hmm. That should be fine, as far as I can see. Maybe I've missed something - will take a look.

EDIT: Nope, having compiled your code, I don't see any problems using `GetAge`. But you *do* have problems trying to access `gender` - maybe that's what you were thinking of? This compiles fine:

```
return string.Format("{0,-6}{1:-15}{2,-9}{3,-24}{4:-12}",
                     "CAT", PetName, Gender, breed, base.GetAge());
```

(Not that you need to qualify `GetAge` with `base`, as it's not overridden in `Cat`. Just `GetAge()` would be fine.)